# Can I create an oracle user that allows only JDBC connections?

Tags: oracle

I need to create a user in an oracle database that only allows connections through JDBC and not through some IDE for example, is this possible?

Comment: What do you think Oracle's default SQL Developer uses to connect to database? Please, describe, what is the task you want to solve

Answer (score 0):

There's no good, foolproof way to do what you're asking (limit connections based on connection protocol, or other client-side parameters). Any of the session parameters that you could base a database logon trigger or smart application role on can be spoofed or altered to bypass your security filter. The generally accepted approach is to secure a user account's permissions so that it doesn't matter how they connect - their access to and view of the data is always the same.

If you want to limit access just to your application server, do this using firewall rules on the database server that only allow inbound connections from the app server IP on the database port, or (if you have Enterprise Edition) use Oracle Connection Manager to filter access by IP address and Oracle Service Name.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it hard to set this up really securely.

You can use such an approach:

- Create DB user with no privileges on Application schema (except for connect)
- Grant user password protected ROLE: APP_ROLE. Having access to APP_SCHEMA tables.
- In your app, after DB logon execute:

  ```
  SET ROLE APP_ROLE IDENTIFIED BY "some role's password";
  ```
- Then execute:

  ```
  ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA='APPL_SCHEMA';
  ```

So even if anybody know username and password for database, he can connect, but is not allowed to see any data. APP_ROLE's password is hard-coded in your app, or is passed to your app from outer source (config file or databases global context).

So basically you need two passwords to access database data:

- user's password
- role's password

Comment: Suppose there were such a method to allow only JDBC.  A lot of the IDE you want to block themselves use JDBC.  I think this is yet another x-y question.

Comment: A hard coded password or password available in a config file is not particularly secure.

Comment: @EdStevens  this is quite common application design. Image SUID application, user can execute it but can not read its text. So user does not have access to ROLE's password. Without ROLE's password user can connect into database, but can not access any data.

Comment: Another option is to SET role via LOGON trigger, if and only if connection as opened from particular application server.

Comment: It is common, but still bad practice. The environment I work in would never authorize (and in fact has rejected many) applications with this architecture (hard coded passwords). I once researched an app where the developer had even posted the snippet of code with the password (same password for all customers, handling sensitive financial data!) on a Google forum looking for help with a bug. It took about 10 seconds to lift the unencrypted password from the compiled code and hack the app, even without that. A secure application role would be better, but still isn't foolproof.

Comment: @pmdba I'd afraid you are triggered by something which is not important at all. Purpose of password protected role is exactly  this case. In order to access database data you  need two secrets (not only one). "hardcoded" might mean jar/exe file is modified *after* compilation by security team. harcoded also can mean that it is provided by external library developers do not have access to. There can  be various ways how to completed the 2nd secret. Developers and even Appl server admin do not have to have access to it. But still without 2nd secret nobody can see database data.

Comment: @ibre5041 - you are talking about not being able to access data _after_ a connection is made.  The OP's question was about _allowing the connection in the first place_, not restricting access to data after a connection is made.

Comment: @EdStevens - something like that impossible to achieve. Possible solutions are: restricting IPs in listener.ora, Logon trigger failing, when connection is not opened from certain IP. But those might be bypassed. The 3rd possible solution is to use 2 secrets.

Comment: @ibre5041 - I know it's impossible.  My first comment in this thread was intended to get the OP to realize that for himself.  No, I don't spoon feed answers.  I take the Socratic approach of asking questions designed to get people to discover the answer themselves. They learn more that way.